# Help with axler's definition of a polynomial (linear algebra done right)

Tags: linear-algebra, notation

I'm having trouble following Axler's polynomial definition. I don't understand the meaning of $$p\colon {\bf F}\to {\bf F}$$  [on page 10 of Axler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ust6k.png)

Further, how would I go about rigorously verifying that ${\cal P}({\bf F})$ is a vector space?

Comment: The notation $p \colon {\bf F}\to {\bf F}$ means that $p$ is a function with domain and range both equal to $\bf F$. To verify ${\cal P}({\bf F})$ constitutes a vector space you  have to check that the set satisfies the vector space axioms. Can you give that a try, and show us what you get? (Typically MSE wants you to 'show work').

Comment: They gave us addition and scalar multiplication, so I'll move on to associative, commutative, etc.

Comment: associative: p(z)+q(z)+t(z)=(p(z)+q(z))+t(z). commutative: (z)+q(z)=q(z)+p(z). distributive: p(z)(q(z)+t(z))=p(z)q(z)+p(z)t(z). additive inverse: p(z)+(-p(z))=0. multiplicative identity: p(z)(1)=p(z).  additive identity: p(z)+0=p(z). All for z contained in F and p, q, and t are all polynomials. Is this sufficient?

Comment: A follow-up is that further in the book, it asks to verify that {p∋P(F):p(3)=0} is a subspace of P(F) and my lack of understanding of polynomials is further exposed. I know I need to show that it has an addititive identity and is closed under addition and multipliction, but I'm having trouble identifying what the elements of a polynomial are (to take an approach similar to the typical n-tuple ordered lists, which I found straightforward). Here's what I have so far: let p1=(z-3)(a0+a1z...) because z=3 is a root and sort of the same for p2=(z-3)(a'0+a1'z'+a2'z'^2...).Then p1+p2 also has z=3 root

Comment: Then I defined Alpha as a scalar in F and then say (Alpha)p1=(Alpha)(z-3)(a0+a1z....) and verify z-3 is still a root. If I'm right I think I could have combined this two-part proof into 1 distributive proof with (Alpha)(p1)+(Beta)(p2)=(z-3)(... but idk if thats normally a good idea. I guess I might have solved this verification but I'm still sort of weirded out thinking of polynomials as vectors.

Comment: I'll try to get back to you over the weekend (maybe tomorrow night) if nobody else does before then....

Comment: Don't worry: You won't ever need this definition of a polynomial, since almost no one in mathematics uses it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue/point is that the book defines the set of polys by viewing polys as $\bf F$-valued functions, and then uses the properties of their image $\bf F$ to define the corresponding properties for functions.  For instance:

- if $p,q$ are $F$-valued functions, then Axler defines $r = (p+q)$ to be the unique function such that $r(z ) = p(z)+ q(z)$, for all $z\in {\bf F}$.
- Likewise, the scalar multiplication is defined 'pointwise' - namely, if $a\in {\bf F}$, and  again viewing a poly $p$ as a function, then we define $s = a p$ to be the unique function such that $s(z) = a p(z)$, for all $z\in {\bf F}$.
- The 'O' function is also defined pointwise, namely by the rule $0(z)= 0$, for all $z$.
- etc.

Now, since Axler gives the definitions 'pointwise', as above, the space of functions automatically inherits all of commutative, associative, distributive, additive inverse - and so on - properties from ${\bf F}$.  In particular, the set of ALL functions from ${\bf F}$ to ${\bf F}$ is automatically a vector space, if the vector space operations/axioms are given pointwise.  So I would say you don't really have to verify commutativity, say, as you wanted to do in your comment, if you believe/understand/say the 'inherit' argument.

On the other hand, given the Axler's function/pointwise definitions, you do have to verify that the ${\cal P} (F)$ is CLOSED under addition, scalar multiplication, etc. For instance,

- the function $0 \in {\cal P}({\bf F})$, because it agrees for all $z$ with the poly that has coefficients $a_i = 0$, for all $i$ (Axler's notation);
- if $p$ is the function that be written as the poly $p(z) = a_0 +a_1 z+ \cdots + a_n z^n,$ then the poly $-a_0 - a_1 z - \cdots - a_n z^n$, viewed as a function,  equals the function $-p$, defined pointwise, as Axler does. Hence ${\cal P}({\bf F})$ is closed under negation (i.e., has additive inverses).
- and so on.

Okay?

Your 'show polys vanishing at $3$ is a subspace' question - I would say that your way of doing it works, because polys that vanish at $3$ all have a factor of $z-3$, as you wrote - and that is something that one can prove. (Don't forget in that approach, that $0 = (z-3) 0$, so that you have the zero element.)

On the other hand, you could do it more 'abstractly' - by 'pure thought', as they say - almost without proving or calculating anything... Namely, the set $V_3$ of ALL functions vanishing at $3$ is a sub vector-space of the set of ALL functions (from $\bf F$ to $\bf F$): for instance,

- if $f(3) =0$, and $g(3)=0$, then $(f+g)(3) = f(3) + g(3) = 0 + 0 = 0$, so $V_3$ is closed under addition, etc.

The abstract fact you would need if $A$ and $B$ are sub vector-spaces of some ambient vector $E$, then the intersection $A\cap B$ is also sub-vector space of $E$. For instance, if

- $x,y\in A\cap B$, then $x+y\in A$ (because $A$ is closed under addition). For the same reason $x+y \in B$. Therefore $x+y \in A\cap B$, and $A\cap B$ is closed under addition.
- and so on...

From that 'abstract' point of view, one would take  $A= V_3$, and $B= {\cal P}({\bf F})$, to conclude as a special case that the polys that vanish at $z=3$ is a vector space.

I hope I haven't weirded you out further....

The psychological problem  is that we are all first taught to think vectors to be $n$-tuples, i.e., elements of ${\bf F}^n$. Now  ${\bf F}^n $ is the arch-typical example of a $n$-dimensional vector space - and yes, every $n$-dimensional $ \bf F$ vector space is isomorphic to (i.e., looks like) ${\bf F}^n$. For example, the vector space of polys of at most degree $4$ is isomorphic to ${\bf F}^5$ (namely, use $a_0,\cdots, a_4$).

On the other hand, usually, the isomorphism is not canonical (i.e., basically, equality) - one needs a choice of coordinates. For instance (only for instance), if somebody standing in the steppes of Siberia envisages the expanse around as a two dimensional vector space, how does one match that vector space 'canonically' with the one that one gets from standing somewhere in Antartica? The two vector-spaces are isomorphic to each other and to ${\mathbb R}^2$, but they are not 'canonically' isomorphic to each other.

Hope this helps - and not the opposite! Good luck...

Comment: Thank you that really helps, especially the last part addressing dimensional vector space. Also your abstract version of the proofs is great. Definitely not the opposite of help! Although I was a bit confused by language like "point wise" and "image".